# store unix command error message into file

Tags: unix

I want to store error of unix command into file.

Ex.
cd /test
/test: No such file or directory.
I want to store error "/test: No such file or directory." into file

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
cd /test 2> myFile.txt
```

Comment: That will redirect only stdout, for stderror you must use something like `cd /test &> myFile.txt`

Comment: @ichramm: No, `2>` for redirecting stdout is correct. `&>`will redirect both stdout and stderr (see [http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html]).

Comment: And, more generally: `if cd /test 2>myFile.txt; then : do work in new; else : handle failure; fi`.  Note that the log file will be created in the original directory.